# Is there any way to "uninclude" a file in C++?

Tags: c++, class

I have a class that is only used in one specific part of another class. It is not mentioned in any other parts of the main class. And I include the corresponding header at the top of a file.

Is there any way to "uninclude" the header after I've used it?

What I mean, is that after you "uninclude" the header with the class, references to the class would not be defined, and any calls to the class would throw an error when compiling.

Pseudo-code:

```cpp
// code section where "cubeData" should be visible
#include "CubeData.h"

void mainWidget::createGeoObjects() {
  cube = new cubeData();
  // ...
}

// #uninclude "CubeData.h" - ???
//
// code section where "cubeData" should be invisible
void mainWidget::otherFunction() {
  cube = new cubeData(); // should result in a compile error
  // ...
}
```

Comment: you may want to look into using namespaces

Comment: You might be able to write your own PIMPL wrapper.

Comment: Can you show me how to do that?

Comment: @zixuan: I took the freedom and completed your code example to make the question more understandable, hope I got it right.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The effect of unincluding a header half way through a code file, into which you have included the header at the file start, is supposed to be that the code in the second half acts as if the header has not been included.

This can be achieved by splitting the code file into two parts.
First part includes the header in question (and probably some other headers).
Second part does NOT include the header (but the others again, so that their content IS known).

You might have to put anything from the first half which needs to be visible in the second half into a new header and also include that into both parts.

So in short, create two code files and include what you need into them. Especially do not include what you do not want to be visible.

Comment: @DocBrown thanks for your editing efforts. Do not take the "editing war" the wrong way please. ;-)

Comment: If you want your typos back, feel free to undo my edit, I will then not remove them a second time ;-)

Comment: Naah. There is a saying in my language "If you find a typo you are allowed to keep it.". I just mentioned that I was myself trying to get some typo fixes in while you were busy doing the same. In the end I forced my last edit through, only to then find it was identical to yours. I just wanted to share my smile with you and make sure that you do not feel attacked. not even rejected. @DocBrown

Comment: ... and I was going to write an answer with a very similar content, but you were quicker than me - fortunately I did not even started to write when you post appeared ;-)

Answer (score 7):

No.

Part of this is that includes are part of the **pre**processor. For the actual compiler, code from an included file and code from the including file look the same.

Comment: I am tempted to edit my answer to start with "Yes.". Not to spite you, but to highlight the different approach. I accept that you answer "No." to express that unincluding is not possible as such and agree that preprocessor do not work that way. My answer is on achieving the effect, yours is on doing it strictly as asked. I do not actually see a conflict between the two answers. Have my upvote:

Comment: I guess I was strictly answering the question posed in the title while you were solving the underlying issue.

Comment: And both has value. I might for example have misunderstood the background goal (though by now I have the acceptance tick, but that is in hindsight).