# C: How to name a struct field `errno`?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I want to define a struct:

```c
struct error
{
    int errno;
    /* other information */
};
```

And then I want my code to have error paths that look like this:

```c
struct error my_error;
my_error.errno = errno;
/* set other fields on the error */
```

But if the same translation unit includes `#include <errno.h>`, then `errno` is normally a macro which gets replaced with something else.

Assuming you actually need to access `errno` in that translation unit so you can't just undefine it, is there a way to still have that struct field name?

I don't care if it's by suppressing the expansion for a specific token, or by somehow getting the `errno` token to get generated by other macro expansions which don't then expand further, or whatever method.

Ultimately it doesn't matter and I can just name the field something else like `error` or `error_number` instead. I just don't like being unable to name things what seems to be the most appropriate name.

Comment: That will depend on the implementation. `errno`  is defined by the ISO C standard to be a modifiable lvalue of type `int`, so whether it is an actual "macro" isn't guaranteed.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin as of C11 I believe it's guaranteed/required to be a macro, but also either way portable code must work in the possibility of it being a macro.

Comment: Please explain what you want to achieve and why.

Comment: Well according to a quick check on `gcc`, `#ifdef errno` does indeed return `true`. In that case `#undef errno` is worth a shot.

Comment: @meaning-matters I want to achieve source code where stuff like this is possible: `struct error error; error.errno = errno; /* set other error fields */`, because I think `errno` is self-evidently the most clear and optimal name for that field and it's offensive that C isn't letting me use the most appropriate name for something.

Comment: You can't.  See the first sentence here: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Reserved-Names.html

Comment: @StephenNewell Oh that's a fair point that you can't (and shouldn't! I think that's equally important). If you're confident `errno` is thusly reserved post that as an answer and I'll probably accept it after a bit more thought.

Comment: If you don't want `errno` to be defined, simply don't `#include <errno.h>`. However, this will probably confuse others, and yourself, given enough time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65431310/is-there-any-way-to-uninclude-a-file-in-c/65431390#65431390

Comment: Use `errnum` or `err_no` or some other, non-reserved name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `errno` as an identifier for a user defined object is not a good idea albeit not explicitly forbidden by the C Standard:

> **7.1.3 Reserved identifiers**
>
> Each header declares or defines all identifiers listed in its associated subclause, and optionally declares or defines identifiers listed in its associated future library directions subclause and identifiers which are always reserved either for any use or for use as file scope identifiers.
> — All potentially reserved identifiers (including ones listed in the future library directions) that are provided by an implementation are reserved for any use. No other potentially reserved identifiers are reserved.
> — Each macro name in any of the following subclauses (including the future library directions) is reserved for use as specified if any of its associated headers is included; unless explicitly stated otherwise (see 7.1.4).
> — All identifiers with external linkage in any of the following subclauses (including the future library directions) and errno are always reserved for use as identifiers with external linkage.
> — Each identifier with file scope listed in any of the following subclauses (including the future library directions) is reserved for use as a macro name and as an identifier with file scope in the same name space if any of its associated headers is included.

Furthermore, `errno` is specified in **7.5 Errors `<errno.h>`** as being defined as a macro.

Hence if you do not include `<errno.h>` or if you undefine `errno`, you can name a struct member `errno`, but for reasons explained in other answers, it is probably a bad idea.

You cannot use `my_error.errno = errno;` to set your structure member because the macro `errno` must be undefined for the member to be accessed, hence cannot be used with its original definition to access the global error code.

Here is a possible, albeit not recommended approach:

```
#include <errno.h>

static inline int get_errno(void) { return errno; }

#undef errno

struct error {
    int errno;
    /* other information */
};

int myfunction(const char *filename, struct error *errorp) {
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        errorp->errno = get_errno();
        return -1;
   }
   fclose(fp);
   return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** the C Standard actually does make the above undefined:

> **7.5 Errors `<errno.h>`**
>
> [...]
>
> If a macro definition is suppressed in order to access an actual object, or a program defines an identifier with the name `errno`, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Sorry for the very delayed decision on which answer to accept. They're all good answers and I upvoted all of them back when they were posted, but I think on balance this is the *most directly appropriate answer*, because it *puts together all of the relevant pieces of the standard which interlock to make this impossible* (or only possible by going into UB, and this shows how), without letting the less technical parts upstage that (a perfect answer *could* mention the "you shouldn't" aspects like "it could {hurt readability, be confusing, ...}",, but it would include+prioritize the stuff here).

Answer (score 6):

Because you commented:

> I want to achieve source code where stuff like this is possible ...
> because I think `errno` is self-evidently the most clear and optimal
> name for that field and it's offensive that C isn't letting me use the
> most appropriate name for something.

It's generally a bad idea to override common identifiers that are part of the language, because it confuses people.  And, it will confuse yourself at some point, when you've forgotten you did this; so it's not even advisable in private own projects.

Writing meaningful bug free code is already a very demanding task for humans.  Tricks like this make things more difficult to understand. Meaning matters the most in programming!

Then, I don't think that `errno` is such a great name that asks to be used elsewhere:

- consists of two abbreviated parts: `err` and `no`.
- doesn't use common camel-case `errNo`
- good alternatives are easy/obvious (e.g. `errorNumber`)
- in the example I see `struct error`, not `struct err`, so it seems you don't like the abbr. `err` that much

Finally, if `errno` is a macro, a line like: `my_error.errno = errno;`, which is at the heart of why you want this, **will never be possible** because the CPP won't be able to differentiate between the two `errno`s. QED.

Comment: +1 overall Re: not such a good name: yeah in principle I agree, but `errno` is like it's own name/noun nowadays for a very specific thing. If I see a field called `errno` I trust that either there are only `errno` values in there (or someone is a liar). If I see the field called "error number", well, that could be any number used as part of anyone's error scheme, not necessarily *The `errno`* used by C and many operating system APIs.

Comment: @mtraceur See what you mean now.  You could then use `errnoCopy` or similar.

Comment: Disagree that it would ever be confusing for someone who already grokked `errno` though. I'll admit maybe it can be and I'm just not seeing the mental angle yet... I do see how for people who aren't very familiar with how `errno` works, who just have passing exposure to it rather than intimate familiarity, it could be confusing. But I know that `errno` is always a "global" (even if it's actually thread local, even if it's actually a global function or intrinsic returning a pointer to a location) and a struct field is syntactically never ambiguous with a global namespace thing.

Answer (score 6):

> If a macro definition is suppressed in order to access an actual object, or a program defines an identifier with the name errno, the behavior is undefined.

[https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.5](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.5)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `#undef` to undefine a preprocessor macro, for example :
https://ideone.com/le9aTz

So `#undef errno` should work.

Note that of course you won't be able to use the original definition of `errno` after the `#undef`. If your struct `error` is defined in one of your header files, any file including that header will not be able to use the original definition of `errno` either.

All in all it's probably better to rename your member variable something different.

Comment: Thanks but that makes `errno` itself inaccessible in the translation unit - sorry I thought that was obviously unwanted I'll edit my question to clarify that.

Comment: I don't think there's a good answer here, just one ugly hack after another.

Comment: Despite my initial comment, have a +1, because at least in some cases #undef might be useful for some people trying to achieve the same thing.

Comment: I doubt that this is entirely portable, too, especially to older machines; however, sometimes the constraints are such that it simply is the easiest way.